# Selenium IDE - Can I store a Selenium variable INTO a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I am trying to take a variable that is in Selenium and assign it to a javascript variable.  I am aware of the storedVars[] associative array.  I can echo the Selenium variables.  But I simply want to assign the Selenium variable INTO a javascript variable.  When doing so, I get the error "ReferenceError: storedVars is not defined".  Is storedVars only recognized by Selenium and not javascript?  Below is code of what I'm trying to do.  I just want to console.log the javascript variable to show that I've assigned the variable.

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://google.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Advertising</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeTitle</td>
    <td>title_se</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${title_se}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>var title_main = storedVars['title_se'];</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>console.log(&quot;The stored page title is &quot; + title_main);</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no error in your script and it was executed without any error.

Following worked with Selenium IDE 2.9.1

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://google.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Advertising</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeTitle</td>
    <td>title_main</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var title_uc=storedVars["title_main"].toUpperCase();title_uc</td>
    <td>uc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${title_main}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${uc}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```